# Split one function into two

Tags: php, laravel-4

for the reusability, I plan to split my function into two functions. Basically, the concept of the function is loads the input file then preview the data.

Working Code

```
public function uploadImportCsv()
    {
        $file = Input::file('file');
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = sha1($file->getClientOriginalName().time()) . ".{$extension}";
        //upload to s3
        #doing upload to s3

        $data = [
            'title'=>[],
            'value'=>[]
            ];
    $results = Excel::load(Input::file('file'), function($reader){

            })->get();
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
            if(!in_array($key, $data['title'])){
                array_push($data['title'], $key);
            }       
        }
        array_push($data['value'], $result);
    }

        return Response::json(['filename' => $filename, 'data' => $data]);
    }
```

after split

```
public function previewCsv()
    {
        //Preview table
        $data = [
                'title'=>[],
                'value'=>[]
                ];
        $results = Excel::load(Input::file('file'), function($reader){

                })->get();
        foreach ($results as $result) {
            foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
                if(!in_array($key, $data['title'])){
                    array_push($data['title'], $key);
                }       
            }
            array_push($data['value'], $result);
        }
        return Response::json(['data' => $data]);
    }

    public function uploadImportCsv()
    {
        $file = Input::file('file');
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = sha1($file->getClientOriginalName().time()) . ".{$extension}";
        //upload to s3
        #doing upload to s3

        $data = $this->previewCsv();


        return Response::json(['filename' => $filename,'data' => $data]);
    }
```

I called the function from the preview function but it does not work.

Comment: First ting you should do is, use a debug tool like xdebug

Comment: @Oshanz Alright, the `$data` is null. How could I pass the $data from previewCsv() into uploadImportCsv() function?

Comment: what is the $data value inside "previewCsv" function? does breakpoints workes there?

Comment: @Oshanz The $data will return two arrays, the first array is `title` to read the first row of csv. The second array is `value` which combined with the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need same result, it's not necessary to return a json object from previewCsv funtion.

```
public function previewCsv()
{
    ....
    return $data;
}
```